# Adding custom "tabs" to Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, customization, facebook-apps

I created a Small Business Facebook page and tried to setup some sort of a *Welcome* page/tab or similar. As I was checking web resources I suppose I should be adding Facebook App to my page that would allow me to create an additional *Tab* on the left.

First of all I'm not sure if that's the correct procedure to create custom tabs on the left with some fancy looking content in the middle area (when tab is clicked).

Anyway. I'm used to having a possibility **Apps** in my personal profile, but I can't seem to find any here, so I would be able to add new apps. But even if I do get to Page settings and click **Apps** All I can see are 5 apps that I can either configure or remove (Photos, Links, Notes, Events and Video). No app directory or anything so I could choose from. Facebook help also seems outdated, because screenshots show a completely different looking interface (actually showing tabs at the top and not links as menu on the left).

This is how my left *menu* choices look like:

[image]

There's no **App** possibility here...

### What am I supposed to do?

Comment: It is no longer possible to add app tabs to a personal profile, but you can add any app to your page just by going to the app profile page and clicking "Add to My Page".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For future reference

I managed to add a custom tab by using [this Facebook app](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=190322544333196). I was a bit confused because at first it asked me to use Facebook as me, so I though *this surely isn't for a Facebook Page*, but afterwards it asked me which Page I would like to add it to. So I selected my desired Facebook Page and that was it.

> I'm a bit disappointed that nobody bothered to answer my question since it seems that this application is quite heavily used in Facebook community.